# android app crashed after opening app and pressing back button and reopening app and pressing back button

Tags: android

Thanks for your watching

I am making my first app in Android.

This app has a welcome Activity(first Activity) and a main Activity(second Activity).

Now here is the problem, when I open my app and press back button to home screen and reopen app and press back button to home screen and reopen app, just quickly do this several times, then the app crashed and even the mobile restarted.

The following is my welcome Activity XML, I tried to remove `android:src="@drawable/welcome"`,app just worked normal, but I didn't know what is the real problem is,I really need a welcome picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="example.givemepass.splashscreendemo.SplashActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am sorry my English is poor.

Thanks for your watching.

ADD logcat:

```
12-04 10:26:34.424 8843-8843/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-04 10:26:34.456 8843-8843/tw.com.cwgv.rs W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
12-04 10:26:34.545 8843-8858/tw.com.cwgv.rs I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2640(199KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 26MB/26MB, paused 9.161ms total 15.174ms
12-04 10:26:34.602 8843-8890/tw.com.cwgv.rs D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-04 10:26:34.610 8843-8843/tw.com.cwgv.rs D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-04 10:26:34.654 8843-8890/tw.com.cwgv.rs I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                          Build Date: 07/13/15 Mon
                                                          Local Branch: mybranch11906725
                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.26
                                                          Local Patches: NONE
                                                          Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030 + 6151be1 + a1e0343 + 002d7d6 + 7d0e3f7 +  NOTHING
12-04 10:26:34.656 8843-8890/tw.com.cwgv.rs I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-04 10:26:34.669 8843-8890/tw.com.cwgv.rs D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

ADD WelcomeActivity.java:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Handler startMainActivity_Handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable startMainActivity_Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startMainActivity();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Some tag", Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause()));
        }

            startMainActivity_Handler.postDelayed(startMainActivity_Runnable, 2000);

            View currentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            currentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startMainActivity_Handler.removeCallbacks(startMainActivity_Runnable);
                    startMainActivity();
                }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        startMainActivity_Handler.removeCallbacks(startMainActivity_Runnable);
        WelcomeActivity.this.finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    protected void startMainActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent().setClass(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        WelcomeActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace from logcat

Comment: App works normal on simulator,only crashed on mobile. I have added on my logcat,thanks!

Comment: It doesn't looks like a stack trace

Comment: that part of log is not your stacktrace. look for the red text.

Comment: hi guys... I have added try catch..but it still doesn't show any red part catlog..did I have the wrong way?  thanks.....

Comment: I find some rules, I change welcome picture from 640x715 to 292x325, and app don't crash anymore.
It seems if I ensure the picture is loaded completely before press back button,the app will work normal...